# Why spring cloud consul doesn't work with standalone tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

Spring cloud consul works as expected when run code inside a spring boot with embedded tomcat.

It doesn't work when we deploy code on the standalone tomcat.It appears there is a `ConsulAutoServiceRegistrationListener` which starts consul service registration on `WebServerInitializedEvent`. This event is only triggered when we run code inside a spring boot with embedded tomcat.

There are couple of workarounds provided at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/302 but none of them work any longer with latest `Greenwich.RC2` release.

What are the other ways we can kick off the service registration on the standalone tomcat ?

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: When I say the title I was going to look for the issue you mentioned. What happens with Greenwich.RC2?

Comment: @spencergibb Thank you for response. for example in the Greenwich.RC2 there is no longer `setPort` method in the `ConsulAutoServiceRegistration`  that we used to set the port as mentioned in the solution here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/302#issuecomment-342340582. It has been replaced with setPortIfNeeded but that is pacakge protected. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Also as a side question what was the reason behind initializing consul auto registration on the spring boot `WebServerInitializedEvent` instead of spring `ContextRefreshedEvent`  event.

Comment: the port isn't available until `WebServerInitializedEvent` if using a random port.

Comment: I think you can set `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.port=${server.port}` and don't need the `setPort()` method.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Please feel free to add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.port=${server.port}` and don't need the `setPort()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a follow-up post, the answer above is still valid. Today I had the same issue, my Spring Boot application didn't register itself to Consul while running on an external Tomcat Server. Although one could come up with a working solution based on all information mentioned in the posts above, I have provided all information here, in one post.

I did have to change one thing in the [solution code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/302#issuecomment-342340582), the annotation `@AutoConfigurationAfter(...)` was used. I had to change it to `@AutoConfigureAfter(...)`

---

## Solution

Add following `MyConsulLifecycle` to your application, based on [solution code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/302#issuecomment-342340582):

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnConsulEnabled
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(type= "org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulLifecycle")
@AutoConfigureAfter(ConsulAutoServiceRegistrationAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyConsulLifecycle implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ConsulAutoServiceRegistration registration;

    public MyConsulLifecycle(ConsulAutoServiceRegistration registration) {
        this.registration = registration;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        if (registration != null ) {
            registration.start();
        }
    }
}
```

As opposed to [Brian Peterson's](https://github.com/bdpeterson) solution, the method `setPort()` is no longer available. This was already mentioned by [Sagar Veeram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/sagar-veeram) in the comments on his post.

As [spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb) said, this is solved by setting the `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.port=${server.port}` in the `application.properties` file:

```
server.port=8080
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.port=${server.port}
```

Note that is is a bit strange to have a `server.port` property required when using a standalone Tomcat Server.